# Polynomial-time reduction

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

How can I prove it?

1. $A \le_p B \Leftrightarrow \overline{A} \le_p \overline{B}$.
2. $A \in \mathcal P \Leftrightarrow \overline{A} \in \mathcal P$.

$\overline{A} = \Sigma^* \setminus A$

Comment: Both properties are really easy once you understand the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can easily be proven by expanding definitions.

1. If $A \leq_p B$, then there exists a polynomial time computible function f such that:
   \begin{align*}
   x \in A \iff f(x) \in B
   \end{align*}
   However, this is equivalent with 
   \begin{align*}
   x \not \in A \iff f(x) \not\in B
   \end{align*}
   and thus $\overline{A}\leq_p \overline{B}$. The other direction is analogous.
2. Suppose $A \in \mathcal{P}$, then there exists a polynomial time Turing machine $M$ that decides $A$. We now construct a Turing machine $M'$ that outputs exactly the opposite of $M(x)$. Clearly $M'$ decides $\overline{A}$ and still runs in polynomial time, thus $\overline{A} \in \mathcal{P}$. The other direction is analogous.